# Taylor series for tan x about the point 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Write down the Taylor series for tan x about the point 0.
Also write down a precise remainder term Rn(x).
finding this much harder than the Taylor series for cos x, arctan x about the point 0.

stuck in this problem from our tutorial sheet of course MA105

Comment: Did you see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: @Nosrati I want to find using taylor's theorem

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I can write for cos x , arctan x about point 0

Comment: How do you do it for $\cos x$ for example ?

Comment: You should tell us what MA105 is, because the naming is different at every school.

Comment: There is no nice "closed-form" formula for the coefficients of this series, although they can be written using [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Taylor_series).  I really don't know what your instructor wants as a "precise remainder term".

Comment: have you studied at IIT bombay and your instructor was Ravi Raghunathan

Answer (score -1):

You can use long division to divide the Maclaurin expansions of sin(x) over cos(x)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET3qjWs7g7w This guy explains it in 5mins